# error visual studio 2010 SQL INTERSECT

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

So I'm trying to find in my db two IDs with the same value at specific column i.e.

```
SELECT SALARY FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID='1'
INTERSECT
SELECT SALARY FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID='5'
```

So I did in VS2010

```
Dim ConnectionString As String
ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=C:\\;Extended Properties=dBase  IV"
Dim dBaseConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
dBaseConnection.Open()
Dim myQ As String = "SELECT 'SALARY' FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID='1' INTERSECT SELECT 'SALARY' FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID='5'"
Dim dBaseCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(myQ, dBaseConnection)
Dim dBaseDataReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = dBaseCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
```

And I get this error when the last line is executed

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
>   Additional information: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).*

Impossible to believe, when I use UNION instead of INTERSECT works

Any ideas, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly answering your question to resolve your error, but anyway this may be a workaround for what you are trying to do.

Instead of using intersect, you can use this query:

```
select salary
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.Salary = Table2.Salary
where Table1.Id = '1' and Table2.Id = '5'
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though you are using the Microsoft JET provider for dBase IV files.  dBase and Microsoft Jet do not support the intersect command.